# Webspere 5.1 on IBM RAD 7.5.4

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I've to add a runtime of websphere 5.1 on my RAD 7.5.4, but I can only add runtime of websphere version 6, 6.1 or 7.

There is anyway to install ws 5.1 in my config?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are out of luck. WAS 5.1 is pretty outdated. It is already unsupported since 2008.
You could try getting an older RAD, but I'd guess IBM probably removed the older downloads as they are unsupported as well.